# How to delete to make distinct by some keys in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data in database which has keys `key1, key2, date`.

I wanna find records which is not distinct by `key1, key2` (I mean unique composite), and make it unique composite, by deleting to leave the oldest record by `date` column.

What is the easiest query to do this?
I am using BigQuery's standard query, but any RDBMS is ok.

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can use a mix of group by keys to get the list of items to keep in database, and then delete the rest of items.

```
DELETE table.* from table,
(
select DISTINCT MIN(date) mindate, key1, key2
FROM table
GROUP BY key1, key2
) tmp
WHERE table.key1 = tmp.key1 and table.key2 = tmp.key2
and table.date <> tmp.mindate
```

This is a SqlFiddle to show the values about to be deleted
(It used a SELECT instead of a DELETE)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d774f/1

Comment: @Taichi, This syntax is working on MySQL. Actually the subquery (tmp) return fields `mindate`, `key1` and `key2` like a temporary table. I've added a SqlFiddle link to test the query

Answer (score 1):

This gives the oldest row in accordance with `date`:

```
SELECT
  key1,
  key2,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    (SELECT AS STRUCT t.* EXCEPT key1, key)
    ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM dataset.table AS t
GROUP BY key1, key2
```

The `ARRAY_AGG` function uses the `ORDER BY` clause to find the oldest row (denoted with `t`) and then expands it using `.*` applied to the bracket operator.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend that you delete the records.  This is not usually a good idea in BigQuery.  I, at least, like to keep the history.

I would start with a view:

```
create view v_t as 
    select t.* except (seqnum)
    from (select t.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by key1, key2 order by date desc) as seqnum
          from t
         ) t
    where seqnum = 1;
```

If you are trying to save money on subsequent queries, then you can materialize the view (i.e. store it into a table) as you need to.

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to just group by it and use an aggregation function in the last column? defining the view like `select key1, key2, min(date) from table group by 1, 2` and using the where clause to elaborate on the definition

Comment: @FKrauss . . . Presumably, the table has columns that are not keys.